# Replace spaces with hyphens in target field of csv file header records

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Parent batch script runs pythons scripts, which retrieve CSV's from a URL. I'm combining these, but some data in one header has spaces which I need to replace with hyphens.

Example: "White Singlet Size 1" becomes "White-Singlet-Size-1" without affecting other headers/fields.

So far I haven't been able to find a script that targets characters in the string without breaking everything.

I'm already using `df.loc` for whole words/fields i.e.

```
df.loc[df['Supplier Stock Level'] > 0, 'Variant Inventory Policy'] = 'Continue'
```

This I use to set `Continue` if greater than `0`, but would love to be able to have something like 'if has spaces', it outputs the same text with hyphens instead of them...

```
df.loc[df['%OLDHEADER%'] replace=" ", '%NEWHEADER%'] = with='-'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following code would work for you?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"to be replaced": [1, 2, 3], "more replacement": [4, 5, 6]})
print(f"initial df:\n{df}")
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "-"))
print(f"final df:\n{df}")
```

prints:

```
initial df:
   to be replaced  more replacement
0               1                 4
1               2                 5
2               3                 6
final df:
   to-be-replaced  more-replacement
0               1                 4
1               2                 5
2               3                 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "-")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   to-be-replaced  more-replacement
0               1                 4
1               2                 5
2               3                 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you looking for a column alias in pandas which are not currently supported as documented at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11723

You can use method .replace on any string object as explained here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace

```
df.loc[df['White-Singlet-Size-1'.replace('-', ' ')]]
```

If you prefer something a little verbose you can first define the name as a constant such as:

```
WHITE_SINGLELET_SIZE_1 = 'White Singlet Size 1'

....
df.loc(df[WHITE_SINGLELET_SIZE_1]])
```

You can also change the column name by using df.columns as specified at:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html

Comment: BTW the answer upvoted is incorrect.  The OP specifically asks for one column name "Parent batch script runs pythons scripts, which retrieve CSV's from a URL. I'm combining these, but some data in one header has spaces which I need to replace with hyphens."  not all of the column names as the map answer clearly implements.

Comment: @TedPossible Please just ignore such ill-informed comments, rather than responding in kind. If you feel sufficiently strongly about it, consider flagging the offending comment instead (see the little flag icon at top left). I agree that it's disappointing to be the target of disrespectful comments like this, but I hope you won't allow one bad apple to spoil your experience. (And welcome to SO, BTW ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a batch file,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.csv" ') DO (
 SET "firstline="
 (
  FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%y IN ("%sourcedir%\%%~nxe") DO (
  IF DEFINED firstline (ECHO %%y) ELSE (SET "firstline=%%y"&CALL ECHO %%firstline: =-%%)
  )
 )>tempfile
 MOVE /y tempfile "%sourcedir%\%%~nxe" >nul
)
```

Where `sourcedir` and `tempfile` are user's-choice.

Simply, for each `.csv` found (name in `%%e`), clear a Boolean flag `firstline`, read each line from `%%e`, on the first, set the flag and replace the spaces in that line with dashes, otherwise regurgitate line verbatim.

Gather output to `tempfile` then overwrite the original file with the modified contents, suppressing the `1 file() moved` message.